# Problema gráfico

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Como arrumar a visualização no eixo y?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open("text.txt") as f:
  data=f.read()
data=data.split('\n')
x=[row.split(' ')[0] for row in data]
y=[row.split(' ')[1] for row in data]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()


text.txt

1 2
2 4
3 1
```

[image: Grafico]

Comment: Qual é o conteúdo de `text.txt`?

Comment: 1 2
2 4
3 1
-----

Comment: Coloque isso na pergunta devidamente formatado, por favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que quando você lê os dados, apesar de serem números no arquivo, eles são strings, por isso o plot interpreta eles como se fossem classes e não valores numéricos. Para resolver isso basta castear para inteiro os valores.

```py
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    data = """1 2
    2 4
    3 1"""

    data = data.split('\n')

    x = [row.split(' ')[0] for row in data]
    y = [row.split(' ')[1] for row in data]

    # casteia os valores para inteiro
    x = [int(element) for element in x]
    y = [int(element) for element in y]

    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()
```

[image: Plot dos valores]